# How to perform string operations on the Key of Associative array in TCL

Tags: arrays, hashmap, tcl

I have an associative array or Hash, is there a way where I can do manipulation on the Key of the Hash.

Forexample: Lets say I have a set of keys in the Keyset of Hash, I want to do some operations(Some string manipulation) on these keys.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array names myarray` to retrieve a list of all the keys, then you can do any string manipulation as you want on them

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure from your question whether you're talking about an array or a dictionary value; both are associative maps, but arrays are collections of variables and dictionaries are first-order values.

You can get the keys of an array with the `array names` command, and of a dictionary with `dict keys`:

```
# Note, access with*out* $varname
set keys [array names theArray]
```

```
# Note, access *with* $varname
set keys [dict keys $theDict]
```

In both cases, the `keys` variable will afterwards hold a normal Tcl list of strings that you can manipulate in any way you want. However, those changes do not reflect back to where they came from (as that isn't how Tcl's value semantics works, and would be really confusing in real code). To change the key of an entry in an array or dictionary, you have to remove the old one and insert the new one; this will (probably) change the iteration order.

```
set newKey [someProcessing $oldKey]
if {$newKey ne $oldKey} {   # An important check...
    set theArray($newKey) $theArray($oldKey)
    unset theArray($oldKey)
}
```

```
set newKey [someProcessing $oldKey]
if {$newKey ne $oldKey} {
    dict set theDict $newKey [dict get $theDict $oldKey]
    dict unset theDict $oldKey
}
```

*From Tcl 8.6.0 onwards* you can also use `dict map` to do this sort of change with dictionaries:

```
set theDict [dict map {key value} $theDict {
    if {[wantToChange $key]} {
        set key [someProcessing $key]
    }
    # Tricky point: the last command in the sub-script needs to produce the
    # value of the key-value mapping. We're not changing it so we use an empty
    # mapping. This is one of the many ways to do that:
    set value
}]
```

If you are changing a few keys in a large dictionary, it is more efficient to use `dict set`/`dict unset` as described earlier: `dict map` is optimized for the case where a lot of changes are being made.